# Disable IPv6 dbug logging in BIND

Tags: linux, bind, named-conf

Using BIND on Arch.

I have `/etc/named.conf` only containing `include "/var/named/named.conf"`
where `named.conf` is:

```
include "/var/named/named.conf.options";
include "/var/named/named.conf.log";
include "/var/named/named.conf.local";
include "/var/named/named.conf.default-zones";
```

I have a flood of

```
lame-servers: info: network unreachable resolving 'foo.bar.net/A/IN': 1234:5678:9abc:def0::1#53
```

and the like in `/var/named/named.run`

From what I read it has to do with IPv6 locally. Have tried various, e.g:

Adding, in `logging {}` of `named.conf.log`:

`category lame-servers { null; };`

in `named.conf.options`:

```
    listen-on-v6 port 53 {
        none;
    };
```

etc.

but to no avail. I have:

```
     channel default_debug {
          print-time yes;
          print-category yes;
          print-severity yes;
          file "named.run";
          severity dynamic;
     };
```

in `logging` and guess I could disable the debug in some way, but rather only silence the `lame-servers` entries. (It is at about 200 MiB and 99.??% is of this kind).

I use NordVPN and it might have something to do with it. I have disabled IPv6 in Nord but still flooding.